# Phpstorm marking valid code as error - Blade templates

Tags: php, phpstorm, laravel-blade

I'm using Blade templating engine (outside Laravel, installed with Composer).

I have a bunch of Blade templates that work fine, but PhpStorm marks them as full of errors:

[image]

Any idea what is wrong?

I have the Blade and Laravel integration plugins installed, just in case it could help - it did not.

Comment: AFAIK PhpStorm does not track variables (usage) between actual PHP code and Blade template. Plus, one of the ideas for using templates is to have code separated from presentation -- here you mix it all together. Anyway: I may only suggest to open a ticket on their [Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) and provide code to reproduce (some simple project -- screenshot is not enough).

Comment: You're probably right with separating code from representation, is there some nicer way than stuffing it all in my "controller" class?